# Check if branch exists in git repo without making a clone

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

I have a huge git repository with a lot of branches. I need to check by shell command inside of Jenkins, if there is a branch inside of repository.

I make a clone of the single branch like this

```sh
if `sshpass -p password git clone -b "${BRANCH}" --single-branch ssh://user@server/GIT/${REPO}.git`; then 
    echo "success"    
else
    echo "ERROR: There is no branch "${BRANCH}" inside repo "${REPO}""
    exit 42
fi
```

It workes right, but it still takes a lot of time to clone a branch. Is there a way to make it work faster (maybe without making clone of repo or with interrupting of cloning if the branch is found)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could parse the output of

```
git ls-remote http://user@server/GIT/${REPO}.git
```

From its [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html):

> Displays references available in a remote repository along with the
>   associated commit IDs.

Comment: That is just great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get only your branches and not tags or anything else you need to do this,

```
git ls-remote -h https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git
```

**P.S: Replace with your remote URL.**

It worked for me,

```
git ls-remote -h https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git

a7c7bb4caf7e68e1713468c3a021d0860a587ac8    refs/heads/independent-scatter
5b22fa99ef80f2004a7439ee6d3c1cfc9c4be010    refs/heads/legacy/v2
f23e872e7573f8c79862ff4822cfc5683703d424    refs/heads/master
03939328cd995043877f97daa1c75c0d5a3ab60c    refs/heads/xcode-8.3
```

Check it out on Github yourself.